# Stage piano outputs to mixer

Tags: piano

My stage piano has left and right outputs (1/4"). They are balanced outputs according to Dexibell.

I have a Yamaha MG10 mixer with several stereo inputs and mono inputs. I understand when using just the left (mono) output from the piano, it "sums" both the left and right outputs into just one signal, supposedly taking care of any phase automatically. I also assume I'm getting both beautiful sides of the piano patch/sample which was originally recorded in stereo...combined into this "mono out" signal.

My question is this: Would there be any benefit whatsoever, if I ran 2 cables..one to the left output and one to the right output of the piano into  a stereo channel of my mixer..thus having my mixer "sum" these 2 signals instead of the piano "summing" them via the L/mono out?

From my mixer, I'm only running one of its outputs to my powered monitor..the other output from mixer is going to FOH. Just need help figuring out the difference or whatever in order to obtain the best sound possible. My JBL powered monitor also has 2 inputs. I'm only using one of them for what is described above. Should I use both inputs of this powered monitor for both outputs of my mixer? ..and send the combined outs from this monitor (via combined output) from this monitor as it can do this.. (JBL SRX812P).. Any of your pro experience is appreciated. Much thanks.

Comment: Is your FOH mono or stereo? You are using one of the main outputs for the monitor?

Comment: FOH is mono. Yes, I'm running an output to my monitor, and the other output to the band's mixer. (Foh)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, they are very unlikely to be balanced outputs from the keyboard if they are 1/4" mono jacks.

> I understand when using just the left (mono) output from the piano, it "sums" both the left and right outputs into just one signal,

This is correct. Usual behaviour for a keyboard.

> if I ran 2 cables..one to the left output and one to the right output of the piano into a stereo channel of my mixer..thus having my mixer "sum" these 2 signals instead of the piano "summing" them via the L/mono out?

Connecting these to a stereo channel will not 'sum' the outputs - they will feed through the mix bus as a stereo signal. They will only 'sum' to mono if you configure the stereo channel into 'mono' mode.

The best sound will be stereo outputs through the desk to a stereo speaker set. This will allow you to leverage the stereo capabilities of the keyboard.

Comment: Again, according to Dexibell, the 1/4" outs from the piano are balanced. This is the most advanced stage piano on the planet, with unlimited polyphony. I was simply curious if the sampled stereo patch would sound better being " summed at the mixer with 2 chan. being used for L and R , so that I could control each signal L and R going to my powered monitor..or let the piano do summing & just run a sngle cable to the mixer. Im not running stereo speakers on stage, but wish i could for personal monitoring, but cant afford another $1000.00 for an additional monitor.Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: with mono speakers it won't make any difference where you sum it.

Comment: And having just checked the manual for the S9 it is clear that the 1/4" jacks are unbalanced. The S9 does have balanced XLR connections which you can use, but these won't mono-sum when you only use the left hand channel. I don't know exactly which keyboard you have but the S9 definitely has unbalanced 1/4" jacks.

Balanced is better for interference rejection, so use balanced XLR cables and sum at the mixer.

Comment: Please accept the answer if that closes the case for you